# Mercurial bulk delete

Tags: mercurial

I've just recently moved a lot of my Views and Controllers into more appropriate locations and am now wanting to pull down recent changes from our central repo.

I've done a `hg pull` which worked fine and asked me to do a `hg update` to bring the changes down locally. This in turn informed me that I needed to do a `hg merge` however when I try this, I get a message stating that

> abort: outstanding uncommitted changes

When I check this using `hg status` I see in the list all of the files that I've moved (so they're now deleted from their old location).

How do I tell Mercurial that I've removed these files? Do I have to go through each one of them and manually do a remove? Is this something that's possible using only the command line rather than doing it with a GUI tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line to automatically `hg rm` the files you've removed you'd:

```
hg addremove
```

It's likely your GUI (you didn't say which you use) exposes that functionality too.

However, that's not what's causing your message.  You have some already made local changes that mercurial does know about (unlike the removed files which it doesn't know about until you tell it), and you need a `hg commit` before you can merge.

Comment: `hg rm --after` is better for this case

Comment: Thanks @Ry4an. I had infact already done a hg commit before receiving this message. It was just complaining about the deleted files.